llamar un datatable con datos en varias vistas desde un archivo javsacript
Tengo un problema en un proyecto en MVC C# y Sql Server utilizo datatables, he creado un archivo JavaScript que llena y muestra los datos que trae del SQL Server en un datatable y lo muestra en un modal desde una vista hasta ahí todo bien.
El detalle es cuando pongo la función en la vista si me muestra la tabla con los datos en el modal, pero cuando la función que es un archivo JavaScript lo pongo en un archivo JavaScript y lo llamo no me funciona es decir no carga la tabla.
Lo que se desea conseguir es que el archivo JavaScript donde esta la función que llena la tabla lo voy ha llamar en diferentes vistas.
Ejemplo la función del archivo JavaScript llena la tabla de ubigeo en un modal, y lo voy ha utilizar en diferentes vistas cuando realice el llamado por ejemplo en una vista cliente, en una vista proveedor etc.
Creo que el problema es que no lo esta reconociendo el datatable en un archivo JavaScript.
el srctip lo pongo en la vista asi:


var tabubi;
$(document).ready(function() {
  //-- Todo sobre Cliente.
  //Obtener Ubigeo
  tabubi = $('#tabUbi').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
      "url": "/Ubigeo/UbiObt",
      "type": "GET",
      "datatype": "json"
    },
    "columns": [{
        "data": "UbiCod",
        "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
          return "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-success ml-1' type='button' onclick='UbiSel(" + JSON.stringify(row) + ")'><i class='fas fa-check'></i></button>"
        },
        "orderable": false,
        "searchable": false,
        "width": "20px"
      },
      {
        "data": "UbiCod"
      },
      {
        "data": "UbiDep"
      },
      {
        "data": "UbiPro"
      },
      {
        "data": "UbiDis"
      }
    ],
    "language": {
      "url": "@Url.Content(~/Content/datatable/datatable.es-ES.json)"
    },
    "responsive": true,
    "lengthChange": true,
    "autoWidth": false,
  });

  function BusUbi() {
    tabubi.ajax.reload();
    $('#ModUbi').modal('show');
  }

  function UbiSel(json) {
    $("#TxtUbi").val(json.UbiCod);
    $("#TxtDep").val(json.UbiDep);
    $("#TxtPro").val(json.UbiPro);
    $("#TxtDis").val(json.UbiDis);
    $('#ModUbi').modal('hide');
  }
});
<div class="modal fade" id="ModUbi" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="mod-cab modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Ubigeo :</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table id="tabUbi" class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped table-hover" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Ubigeo</th>
                    <th>Dpto</th>
                    <th>Provincia</th>
                    <th>Distrito</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-flat" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>





Buenas, podrías mostrarme como estás llamando el archivo de JS a tu pagina de HTML?

Hola Eduardo, gracias el escript que lo pongo en la vista es asi:   

Al revisar el inspeccionar elemento de la página recibes algún error en intentar cargar los datos?

a mi parecer creo que el problema es que no lo reconoce por la url del datatable que esta en el script, creo que eso fuera eso el error.

No me sale ningun error Eduardo, el srctip lo pongo en la misma vista ahi si me carga y me muestra el modal con los datos, pero cuando coloco el script en un archivo JS y lo llamo ahi no me muestra los datos ni siquiera carga el modal.

Puedes intentar modificando la url del script de la siguient manera "url": window.location.origin+"/Ubigeo/UbiObt"

ok Eduardo. voy a probar en estos momentos.

Eduardo cambia la url de esta manera pero no carga

"url": window.location.origin + "/Ubigeo/UbiObt",

te comento que he hecho lo mismo pero llamando un script para que me cargue datos en los combobox y eso si me sale bien. en esa parte no tengo problema.

$(document).ready(function () {
jQuery.ajax({
"url": "/TabArt/ComTia",
type: "GET",
data: null,
dataType: "json",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
success: function (data) {
$("").attr({ "value": "" }).text("Seleccionar").appendTo("#CboTia");
$.each(data.data, function (index, value) {
$("").attr({ "value": value.TagCod }).text(value.TagDes).appendTo("#CboTia");
});
},
error: function (error) {
console.log(error)

Gracias Eduardo ya pude resolver el caso.

@WillianEdgarEvangelioAvila pon siempre como edición a la pregunta los detalles y aclaraciones relevantes. Los comentarios son efímeros, además de que, como notarás, el código es ilegible en los comentarios.

Además, si ya has encontrado una solución, ponlo como respuesta, en base a [answer].

Hola Padaleiana, gracias por las recomendaciones y las aclaraciones voy a realizar lo indicado.
